# Python tkinter-multiple frames

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have started learning python.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujOes.png)
I was trying to make a tkinter multiple frame application. 
But the output is something like this. I can't figure out why "page Three" button is showing in every frame, I tried to figure out but can't. I am a newbie. Please help me.
Thanks a lot.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


Large_Font=("Verdana",16)

class First(tk.Tk):#inherited tk.Tk
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

       # self.iconbitmap(default='favicon.ico')
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self,"First one!")

        container = tk.Frame(self)#always have this, frame is predef frame is edge of window
        container.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand=True)# fill is for limits you set and expand is to go beyond if needed
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)#0 is min value, weight specs priority
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames={}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):

            frame = F(container,self)
            self.frames[F]=frame
            frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="ew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame=self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        label=ttk.Label(self,text="Hello World",font=Large_Font)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self,text="PageOne", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        button1=ttk.Button(self,text="PageTwo",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button1.pack()

        button2=ttk.Button(self,text="Page Three",command= lambda: controller.show_frame(PageThree))
        button2.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label=tk.Label(self,text="Welcome to Page 1",font=Large_Font)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self,text="To Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self,text="To PageTwo", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button1.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label=tk.Label(self,text="Welcome to Page 2",font=Large_Font)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self,text="To Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self,text="To PageOne", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.pack()


class PageThree(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        label=ttk.Label(self,text="Graph page",font=Large_Font)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self,text="To Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self,text="To PageOne", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.pack()




app=First()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: So you want a single window, that changes the contents inside it or you want multiple windows?

Comment: i want multiple windows, but the button for Page Three is shown in every frame

Answer (score 0):

The different frames do not overlap etirely. If you give each frame a different background colour you'll be able to clearly see what is going on. For example:

```
class PageThree(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent, bg='thistle')
```

and then do this for each of your pages.

So, either make the pages the same size or use `pack_forget()`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="ew")
```

To this:

```
frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")
```

What you are seeing is a result of the pages being different sizes and therefor you are able to see the page containing button 3. Right now you have set your sticky for only east and west however in the north south directions your pages do not stretch to fill their parent. All you need to do to correct this is fix the stick to be in all directions.

There are some other directions you can go with this. Example you can rebuild the main frame every time you call a new page. This may be helpful when you have many pages or different kind of content to display.

You can have everything be one page and simply update the labels and buttons to the new content.

Or you can do what you have already done and simple correct the size of each window/frame being displayed so you do not see any overlap.